# "Access blocked: project-165437914245’s request is invalid" to get a code for Google Assistant SDK

Tags: oauth, oauth2-playground

[OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/install-sample)

With the message below, i cannot get an authorization code for the credentials.

Sign in with Google
Access blocked: project-165437914245’s request is invalid

You can’t sign in because project-165437914245 sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue. Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of project-165437914245, see error details.
Error 400: invalid_request

console
In hte OAuth consent screen,
set Publishing status to In production
set User type to External
in Test users section, add users to my e-mail address